# Descobrir qual componente Primefaces efetuou uma ação utilizando função jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

Quero fazer um `refactoring` em meu código, e para isso preciso pegar o id de um componente que sofreu uma ação.

O meu alvo seria que tenho duas `datatables`, e queria pegar o `id` delas e a partir do `id` definir qual ação a ser tomada.

Então eu tenho as `datatables` conforme a figura abaixo

[image: <code>Datables</code>]

Eu tenho dentro delas as seguintes chamadas para ajax em cada tabela.

```
<p:ajax event="rowEditInit" onstart="disableBtnCorrenteExcluir();"/>
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" oncomplete="if (args.validationFailed) disableBtnCorrenteExcluir(); else enableBtnCorrenteExcluir();"/>
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" oncomplete="enableBtnCorrenteExcluir();" />
```

Para cada tabela eu executo métodos para bloquear os botões Adicionar faixa, Editar vigência e Excluir vigência. O que esta em questão é, se quando eu executar a chamada dos métodos acima nos eventos específicos do `Primefaces`, sera que tem como pegar qual objeto o chamou?

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: Olá Macario, reorganizei a pergunta para colocar deixar a dúvida sequencial. Fique a vontade caso queira reverter a edição se ela não tiver ficado boa ou alterado o que era a dúvida realmente.

Comment: Macario, não consegui compreender bem o que você pretende fazer. Saber o ID do `datatable`depende muito do tipo de evento que você quer capturar e onde será necessária a captura. Talvez eu ou alguém consiga ajudar se você puder tentar detalhar um pouco mais, talvez com exemplos do código onde o evento é configurado e do código onde é necessário recuperar o ID.

Comment: Grande @utluiz, sempre ajudando, cara seguinte, eu tenho duas `datatables`, e eu faço 4 métodos, 2 para cada `datatable`. Eu queria fazer o seguinte, pegar qual componente clicou, porque dentro da `datatable` tem um botão para excluir.  E ai eu queria pegar qual foi clicado, entendeu?

Comment: @utluiz desculpe mas atualizei a pergunta novamente para deixar mais clara. Estava saindo do trabalho e ficava complicado responder.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é exatamente o que você espera, mas ao tratar um evento qualquer (como `onclick`) num elemento que está dentro de um `datatable`, você pode usar o seguinte código JavaScript para recuperar o `id` da tabela:

```js
$(this).closest('.ui-datatable').attr('id');
```

Lembrando que `this` nesse contexto refere-se ao botão que foi clicado.

O código acima localiza nos elementos "pais" do elemento clicado, o primeiro que contém a classe `ui-datatable`.

Isso funciona tanto num `onclick` *inline* na tag do elemento, quanto numa função adicionada com jQuery.